# Parse JSON in flutter - _InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart

I am trying to parse JSON in flutter. I tried with below code.

Sample JSON.

```
{
    "statusCode": 200,
    "message": "",
    "result": [
        {         
            "userName": "RAJ",
            "hierarchyLevel": 3,
            "sequence": 1,        
            "isSuccess": 1
        },
        {
            "userName": "SAM",
            "hierarchyLevel": 3,
            "sequence": 1,        
            "isSuccess": 1 
        },
       
    ]
}
```

My Code is:

```
                  int jsonStatus = response.statusCode;
                  if (jsonStatus == 200) {
                    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
                    if (jsonData["statusCode"] == 200) {
                      List<dynamic> listValJson = jsonData["result"];
                      List<String> userList = new List<String>.from(listValJson);
                    }
          }
```

I am getting below error:

```
Error: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

I know it is basic question for JSON parsing. I tried with Mapping also. But in this case I need list of "userName"'s presented in array. Kindly check my JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For parsing the `json`, you should use the `Model` in `dart` and using the helpers like `fromJson` `toJson` you should contact with the API.

You can use https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/, which will create the `Model` for you , if you paste the `json`.

For example consider using a `Model`.

```
class Model {
  String? userName;
  int? hierarchyLevel;
  int? sequence;
  int? isSuccess;

  Model({this.userName, this.hierarchyLevel, this.sequence, this.isSuccess});

  Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userName = json['userName'];
    hierarchyLevel = json['hierarchyLevel'];
    sequence = json['sequence'];
    isSuccess = json['isSuccess'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userName'] = this.userName;
    data['hierarchyLevel'] = this.hierarchyLevel;
    data['sequence'] = this.sequence;
    data['isSuccess'] = this.isSuccess;
    return data;
  }
}
```

And use it as:

```
final List<Result> result =   (jsonData["result"] as List<dynamic>)
                               .map((item) => Model.fromJson(item as Map<String, dynamic>))
                               .toList();
```

Now you can access any of its child like:

```
debugPrint(result[0].userName); // Raj
```

Answer (score 1):

**result class**

```
class Result {
  String? userName;
  int? hierarchyLevel;
  int? sequence;
  int? isSuccess;

  Result({this.userName, this.hierarchyLevel, this.sequence, this.isSuccess});

  Result.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    userName = json['userName'];
    hierarchyLevel = json['hierarchyLevel'];
    sequence = json['sequence'];
    isSuccess = json['isSuccess'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['userName'] = this.userName;
    data['hierarchyLevel'] = this.hierarchyLevel;
    data['sequence'] = this.sequence;
    data['isSuccess'] = this.isSuccess;
    return data;
  }
}
```

fix your response:

```
final List<Result> listResult =
          (jsonData["result"] as List<dynamic>)
              .map((e) => Result.fromJson(e as Map<String, dynamic>))
              .toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This error is simply says that you are trying to convert Map into String.

```
List<dynamic> listValJson = jsonData["result"];
```

now 'listValJson' is `List<Map<String,dynamic>>` not `List<String>`

Try to create a data model for all user's data or use

```
if (jsonData["statusCode"] == 200) {
                  List<dynamic> listValJson = jsonData["result"];
                  List<String> userList = new List<String>.from(listValJson['userName']);
                }
```

if you want to use only name.